# Javascript not getting data from PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm trying to plot some data using javascript , ajax and php .

This is my `test.php` :

```
    $query=sprintf("SELECT COUNT( `cases_title`) as count ,`cases_title` FROM `classifies` GROUP BY `cases_title`");
    $result=$mysqli->query($query);

    $data=array();
    foreach($result as $row){

    $data[]=$row;
    }
    $result->close();
    $mysqli->close();
    print json_encode($data);

    ?>
```

I printed the output and it was :

```
    [{"count":"7","cases_title":"ANGINA"},{"count":"1","cases_title":"ASTHMA"},{"count":"4","cases_title":"MI"}]
```

So I suppose `test.php` is working.

This is my `app.js` :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost/final/test.php",
        method: "GET",

        success: function(data) {

            console.log(data);
            var cas=[];
            var cou=[];

      //   document.write(data);
            for(var i in data) {

                cas.push(data[i].cases_title);
                cou.push(data[i].count);
            }

            console.log(cou);
            var chartdata = {
                labels: cas,
                datasets : [
                    {
                        label: 'Count',
                        backgroundColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.75)',
                        borderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.75)',
                        hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
                        hoverBorderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
                        data: cou
                    }
                ]
            };

            var ctx = $("#mycanvas");

            var barGraph = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'bar',
                data: chartdata
            });
        },
        error: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
```

`document.write(data)` in app.js returns : `[{"count":"7","cases_title":"ANGINA"},{"count":"1","cases_title":"ASTHMA"},{"count":"4","cases_title":"MI"}]`

However the arrays aren't being filled. They show as `undefined` .  The url to `test.php` is correct.

What is causing the arrays `cou` and `cas` to not be filled? I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Try manually specifying the expected type of `data`. After `method: "GET",`, add `dataType: "json",`

Comment: So I suppose test.php is working." Nope. Your ajax request is not recognizing it as JSON data. Use `header('Content-Type: application/json');` in test.php, or use the parse command in your JS.

Answer (score 0):

you have to parse the response as json with JSON.parse(data) or the other side arround JSON.stringify before transferring valid json data via network.